# Cleaning up function type signatures with type classes

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Given a function signature like this (using the riak package):

```
put :: (Storable a, Resolvable a, ToJSON a, FromJSON a) => Connection -> a -> IO ()
```

would it be a bad idea to clean up the function signature by defining a type class like:

```
class (Storable a, Resolvable a, ToJSON a, FromJSON a) => Persistable a
put :: (Persistable a) => Connection -> a -> IO ()
```

I'm more than happy to hear that this is a stupid idea, but if so, can you tell me why?

Secondly, assuming it's not a bad idea, I can define a catch-all instance by using UndecidableInstances like so:

```
instance (Storable a, Resolvable a, ToJSON a, FromJSON a) => Persistable a
```

However, there has recently been some [discussion on Haskell-cafe](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-June/092760.html) about the cons of using UndecidableInstances, with the general consensus seemingly that requiring it's use points to poor design decisions. Is it a justified usage in this case, or is it better to require explicit boilerplate instances for each type class implementing Persistable?

Comment: This problem is common enough that a language extension (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Context_alias) has been proposed to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "more boilerplate" is almost never the best option. For example, using TH to auto-generate instances is another alternative that some people might find more palatable.

That said, I think `UndecidableInstances` gets a bad rap. Really, what's the worst-case scenario? It makes the compiler go into an infinite loop? A mere trifle. You can write a few lines of pure Haskell 98 that will trigger the worst case complexity for H-M type inference and leave GHC grinding to a halt as it consumes gigabytes of memory, which is frankly worse than an infinite loop that just burns CPU cycles.

The important thing is that the pathological behavior *doesn't occur if you're writing sensible code*, and is generally *easy to diagnose if you do hit it*. You won't get subtle bugs, or weird behavior in instance selection, and you certainly won't get invalid programs to compile. This is no different than the possibility of nontermination at the value level that we deal with *all the time* in programs. In some ways, it's better, because it only causes errors at compile time, not run time.

As it stands, the termination checks used for instances are *ridiculously* conservative. There are plenty of cases that are provably correct, but can't be written without `UndecidableInstances`. And while it would be nice to have a smarter termination checker, or extra features to support common clearly-safe cases (cf. the context alias proposal Heatsink mentioned), there's really no harm at all in using `UndecidableInstances` to implement what you want right now. The most I'd suggest is to isolate its use to a single module with just the aliases, so that you don't have to worry about unintentionally writing non-terminating instances elsewhere.

If memory serves me, most of these points were made by Oleg on haskell-cafe, though I don't have a link handy. He does [talk about it on his website](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html#undecidable-inst-defense), though.

---

In contrast, I think `OverlappingInstances` probably deserves a worse reputation than it currently has. :] It's far more conceptually problematic than `UndecidableInstances`, to my mind.

Comment: Care to elaborate on your doubts about `OverlappingInstances`?

Comment: Also, I'd argue that in practice it's easier to trigger non-termination with `UndecidableInstances` than it is to produce code that makes type inference exponential. At least that was my experience; I wonder what others have to say on the matter.

Comment: `OverlappingInstances` is not as bad as `IncoherentInstances`.

Comment: @Mikhail Glushenkov: I've hit both both equally often when not expecting to, which is to say almost never. The difference is that the situation where one expects to encounter nonterminating instances--i.e., excessively baroque type-level metaprogramming, where you actually *want* Turing-completeness--is of some minor utility, whereas exponential type inference only occurs in code that would be very silly in practice. As for my qualms about overlapping, I'm afraid I can't elaborate clearly off the top of my head or within the space of a comment.

Comment: @augustss: Quite so. Although, `IncoherentInstances` as least has the common decency to *sound* disreputable. Overlapping sounds relatively innocuous at first.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it. You get a shorter type signature for `put`, but will have to litter your code with boilerplate `Persistable` instances. Solving this (second-order) problem with `UndecidableInstances` feels like using a steam hammer to crack nuts, since `UndecidableInstances` [can make the typechecker go in an infinite loop potentially](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2008/04/08/stop-using-undecidable-instances/). In my opinion, the cons outweigh the pros.

[Context aliases](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Class_alias) present a more attractive solution, but unfortunately are not supported in any existing compiler.

Comment: I've never had any problems with this solution, though I wouldn't guarantee there can never be any.

Comment: I guess you can tell that I wound up going with the answer that didn't require me to rewrite the code ;) Context aliases look like they'd be great, if they ever get implemented...